# Active tab click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I setup a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnnsqwsd/.

Basically, I'm trying to recreate http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/, but with a couple changes (changing from ids to data-attributes mostly, so I can have multiple tab modules on a page).

It works, but if you click the first active tab (Tab #1) after the load, it breaks?

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).data("tab");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forget to Add

```
data-tab=".tab-1"
```

to your first li a

```
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1" data-tab=".tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnnsqwsd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first tabs link to

```
<a href="#" data-tab=".tab-1">Tab 1</a>
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/bnnsqwsd/2/

Answer (score 0):

i also use this tab. it nice and small script. i want to how can make auto change one by one. say like each 5 sec next tab will active. something like slider